# Looking for some better tcpdf performance?

Tags: refactoring, tcpdf

I am trying to speed up the pdf creation on my live website ( i didn't look into it in my production enviroment, and now looking in debug.log i see this PHP Fatal error;

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1966080 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/tcpdf_min/tcpdf.php on line 18146
```

So i am looking into tcpdf.org/perfomance and i was wondering if i use the setfont the right way. I set it 8times like so

```
$this->SetFont('helvetica',
```

and only the size or bold is added.

I am using the barcodes_2d and barcodes_1d do i need the UTF-8 Unicode

```
`If you do not need UTF-8 Unicode, set the $unicode parameter on TCPDF constructor to false and the $encoding parameter to 'ISO-8859-1' or other character map.


Edit the config/tcpdf_config.php file: manually set the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], K_PATH_MAIN and K_PATH_URL constants, and remove the automatic calculation part;
```

Means i better use

```
 $image_file = "http://www.mydomian.com/images/our_logo.jpg"; vs $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES . "our_logo.jpg";
```

Any tips, code example for a better tcpdf create pdf performance?

Comment: Two questions: what version of TCPDF are you using and how large are the PDF files that your application creates?

Comment: @JamesG i am using version 6.0.049 last update: 2013-11-27 and the created pdf are of different file size. It depends on the workshop(s) an user selects, for each selected workshop a ticket is created. Question how do i best track/monitor the memory used by and time execution of my application?

Comment: Hmmm... strange. Line 18146 of tcpdf.php in that version has an `if` statement with a call to `strlen()`. Can you copy and paste line 18144-18146 in your version? Based on your description of what the files contain, they should be very small (like under 1MB), which means they shouldn't be taking much memory to process at all. I would recommend commenting out almost all of the code that is constructing the PDF until you have the bare minimum and see if that works. Assuming it does, uncomment the other lines one at a time until you find the one that is causing the memory usage to explode.

Comment: Also, as an alternative to (or in addition to) commenting out lines of code, you could sprinkle calls to `memory_get_usage()` throughout your code to find out where the bulk of the memory usage is occurring. http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: @JamesG really appreciate your suggestion esp. memory_get_usage() never used it in my php code. About the lines `}
    }
   } elseif (strlen($dom[$key]['value']) > 0) {`

Comment: FYI: for this project i have asked the hosting company to spice up the memory of the server to 3gb and i have also set the php memory to 256mb myself with plesk. I know this not the way of real coding ninja, but deadline pressure made me do it ;). I still need/want to increase tcpdf performance. As every ticket is just 30-40kb in size, so allocating 138mb seems a bit too much.

Comment: It is really strange that the script is running out of memory at that particular line of code, but anyway, it is not that line of code that is the problem, it is something happening earlier in the process. One of your assets (a font or an image) must be exceptionally large or is being accidentally added multiple times. I *thought* TCPDF tried to be smart about the same image being added multiple times, but maybe not. As mentioned earlier, you should add a whole heap of logging on the memory usage and you should be able to determine pretty quickly which bit of code is the culprit. Good luck! :)